# '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression. Get capacity from KeyPoint vector OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem with my project, like I wrote in subject. I want to get a capacity from table of `KeyPoint vector`. Please tell me, where is my problem?

Here is my code

```
class SidesOfFigure
{
public:
    SidesOfFigure() {
    };


    ~SidesOfFigure() {
    };

    //sideNumber == 0 => top
    //sideNumber == 1 => down
    //sideNumber == 2 => left
    //sideNumber == 3 => right
    void setSideOfFigure(vector <KeyPoint> keyPoints, int sideNumber) {
        sideOfFigure[sideNumber] = keyPoints;
    }
    uint64 getCapacityOfSide(int numberOfSide) {
        try
        {
            return sideOfFigure[numberOfSide].capacity;
        }
        catch (const std::exception&)
        {
            throw exception("Illegal number!");
        }
    }

private:
    vector <KeyPoint> sideOfFigure[4];
};
```

Comment: capacity is a member function not member variable. Use () to call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the error message itself is relatively strange, the problem is that [capacity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) is a member function of `std::vector`, not a member variable. So you just need to add parentheses to call it: `sideOfFigure[numberOfSide].capacity()`.